# Syntax error at end of input with IF ... ELSE statement

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, plpgsql

I'm running this code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_orders_check()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.type = 'prescription' AND NEW.prescription_id IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Must include prescription_id';
  ELSE IF NEW.TYPE = 'item' AND NEW.item_id IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Must include item_id';
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Type must be either prescription or item';
  END IF;
END
$func$;
```

I get the error:

> ```
> syntax error at end of input
> ```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) it's `ELSIF`

Comment: Man I've been reading through those trying to figure out what I did wrong and completely skipped over that part. Thank you!

Comment: To be complete, `ELSEIF` can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error has been pointed out in the comments. It's `ELSIF` or `ELSEIF`.

**More importantly**, your logic is broken. You would reach the exception
*'Type must be either prescription or item'* when everything is ok.

You most probably want something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_orders_check()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE NEW.type
   WHEN 'prescription' THEN
      IF NEW.prescription_id IS NULL THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Must include prescription_id';
      END IF;
   WHEN 'item' THEN
      IF NEW.item_id IS NULL THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Must include item_id';
      END IF;
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Type must be either prescription or item';
   END CASE;
END
$func$;
```

Using a "switched" `CASE`. See:

- [Display column name with max value between several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067014/display-column-name-with-max-value-between-several-columns/27071163#27071163)

You could also use separate `IF` statements, but this is probably the best way.