# Error in PostgreSQL function with dynamic query for update

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

This is the error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «;»
> LINE 35: END;
> ```

I am trying to create a dynamic execution query to update the drug price for an individual product, for a supplier, or for a laboratory.
This is my function in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mod_medicamento(char,text,char,float)RETURNS void as $$
Declare
/*
$1 for table (L=laboratorio,P=Proovedor(supplier),M=medicamento
$2 for name of lab,supplier or product
$3 paramater for tyoe of operation (A for increment price D for decrement price)
$4 for porcentage(0.01 to 0.99)
*/

tabla ALIAS FOR $1;
nombre ALIAS FOR $2;
operacion ALIAS FOR $3;
porcentaje ALIAS FOR $4;
nombre_tabla varchar(30);
nombre_campo varchar(30);
calculo varchar(20);
BEGIN

    if tabla='L'then
        nombre_tabla:='laboratorio';
        nombre_campo:='laboratorio';
    else if tabla='P'then
        nombre_tabla:='proovedor';
        nombre_campo:='proovedor';
    else if tabla='M' then
        nombre_tabla:='medicamento';
        nombre_campo:='nombre';
    else
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'selecciona una opcion valida (L/P/M)';
    END IF; 

    if operacion='A' then
        calculo:='precio+precio*';
     else if operacion='D' then
        calculo:='precio-precio*';
    else    
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'selecciona una opcion valida de operacion(A/D)';   
    end if;
    
    Execute format('Update medicamento set precio=%L%L where id_%L = (Select id_%L from %I
            where %I like %L)',calculo,porcentaje,nombre_tabla,nombre_tabla,nombre_tabla,nombre_campo,
                  nombre);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `else if` needs to be either `ELSIF` or `ELSEIF` per [Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).

Comment: oh god, that it's, now is running,thank you so much!!
However latter i'll test the all  function  correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) already pointed out the immediate syntax error.
But there is more. Consider this rewrite:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mod_medicamento(_tabla char, _nombre text, _operacion char, _porcentaje float) -- ①
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
/*
$1 table (L=laboratorio, P=proovedor(supplier), M=medicamento
$2 name of lab, supplier, or product
$3 paramater for type of operation (A for increment price, D for decrement price)
$4 for percentage(0.01 to 0.99)
*/
   _nombre_tabla text;
   _nombre_campo text;
   _calculo text;
BEGIN
   -- enforce: $4 for percentage(0.01 to 0.99)  -- ②
   IF _porcentaje > 0 AND _porcentaje < 1 THEN  -- actually in range (0, 1)
      -- all good
   ELSE -- also catches null
      RAISE EXCEPTION '_porcentaje must be in range [0, 1). Was: %', _porcentaje;
   END IF;
   
   CASE _tabla  -- ③
   WHEN 'L' THEN
      _nombre_tabla := 'laboratorio';
      _nombre_campo := 'laboratorio';
   WHEN 'P' THEN
      _nombre_tabla := 'proovedor';
      _nombre_campo := 'proovedor';
   WHEN 'M' THEN
      _nombre_tabla := 'medicamento';
      _nombre_campo := 'nombre';
   ELSE
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'selecciona una opcion valida (L/P/M)';
   END CASE;

   CASE _operacion
   WHEN 'A' THEN
      _calculo := '+';
   WHEN 'D' THEN
      _calculo := '-';
   ELSE
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'selecciona una opcion valida de operacion(A/D)';
   END CASE;

   EXECUTE format(
-- RAISE NOTICE '%'  , format(  -- use instead of EXECUTE for debugging!
$q$
UPDATE medicamento m
SET    precio = m.precio * (1 %1$s %2$s)  -- ④, ⑤
FROM   %3$I t                             -- ⑥
WHERE  t.id_%4$s LIKE %5$L
AND    m.id_%3$s = t.id_%3$s
$q$
    , _calculo, _porcentaje, _nombre_tabla, _nombre_campo, _nombre);
END
$func$;
```

Generates and executes a query of the form:

```sql
UPDATE medicamento m
SET    precio = m.precio * (1 + 0.123)
FROM   proovedor t
WHERE  t.id_proovedor LIKE 'nombre'
AND    m.id_proovedor = t.id_proovedor
```

① Use of [`ALIAS` is discouraged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS). Use named parameters instead.
I like to prefix parameter and variable names with an underscore (`_`) to avoid naming conflicts with column names, but that's optional.

② Actually enforce the allowed range for _porcentaje. (Also disallowing `0` which wouldn't change anything.)

③ A "switched" `CASE` is more efficient & elegant for the use case. Example:

- [Display column name with max value between several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067014/display-column-name-with-max-value-between-several-columns/27071163#27071163)

④ Simplified computation. `precio + precio * 0.123` --> `precio * (1 + 0.123)`

⑤ Your **original concatenation did not work at all** since the format specifier `%L` in [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) adds single quotes that break the syntax.

⑥ Use a [`FROM` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) in the `UPDATE` instead of a correlated subquery. Your original query raises an exception if more than one row matches. Also: faster.

Since you are not returning anything, you may want a `PROCEDURE` instead of the `FUNCTION`. But either works. See:

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)

Dynamic SQL like this is potentially open to SQL injection. But while you don't concatenate user input directly, you are safe.